# Simple Routing with Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

So if I want an edit link, I can do either of the following:

```
link_to 'Edit', edit_user_task_path(@user, @task)
link_to 'Edit', [:edit, @user, @task]
```

If I want to delete one however, I have to do:

```
link_to 'Delete', [@user, @task], method: :delete
```

Is it possible to make rails understand the following?

```
link_to 'Delete', [:delete, @user, @task]
```

It seems like it tries to go to the "delete_user_task_path", is there a shorter form for delete like there is the edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to understand is that the array argument for the link_to method doesn't touch the request method (as far as I know).

As so, your suggestion would actually going to do a GET request to something like /user/:id/delete.

You could make this happen with something like

```
resources :user do
  get :delete, on: :member
end
```

But that's not very RESTful, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Perfect. That's a great answer. Thank you :)